# Cannot format string properly

Tags: python, format

I need to format a proxy list

###.###.###.###:###

to

socks ###.###.###.###  ###  (usename) (password)

I have it working except that username and password are not in right spot

```
heres code:`file = "proxys.txt"
socks = "socks5  "

oauth = input("Enter Username and Password. If no auth leave blank:  ")

with open(file, 'r') as fp:
    ips = [socks.join(['', x.replace(':', ' '), oauth]) for x in fp.readlines()]

with open(file, 'w') as fp:
    fp.writelines(ips)
```

I tried to make a function that writes oauth after string but failed

I can't seem to make it work

Comment: Please, add the full error traceback

Comment: there is no error at all and no warnings it is that output is in wornig format ,

Comment: and how it "failed"?

Comment: it is supposed to format like this : socks5 ip port <input>

Comment: it formats incorrectly

Comment: it formats incorrectly it supposed to take list of ips like this                                                       111.111.111.111:8080                   to    socks5 111.111.111.111  8080 user passs